# After INSERT INTO in DO block query an SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to insert stuff into two different tables. This works also everything. However, I would like to make a `SELECT` at the end of the two `INSERT INTO`. However, this does not work. Does anyone have an idea how to put this into a statement?

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
myid tbl_groupchat.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.tbl_groupchat(
        chatname, createdate)
VALUES ('test4', CURRENT_DATE)
RETURNING id INTO myid;
INSERT INTO public.tbl_participants (
         id_groupchat, id_profile)
         VALUES (myid, 2);
         
SELECT *
FROM public.tbl_participants
WHERE id_profile = 2;
END $$
```

output

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

tbl_participants

[image]

tbl_groupchat

[image]

I tried this

```
RETURN(SELECT id_profile
FROM public.tbl_participants
WHERE id_profile = 2);
```

output

```
ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void
LINE 13: RETURN(SELECT id_profile
               ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 279
```

Comment: Please note that `DO` block will never return data because its return type is void. so select query is not allowed here. if you want to do that then either use function or use `refcurser`

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. Could you show me in code how I would have to rewrite the statement?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution using cursor:

Assign the output of your select query output in cursor and fetch it out of DO block but with in same session.
Considering your insert and select queries are working fine individually then write your do block like below.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
myid tbl_groupchat.id%TYPE;
ref_cursor REFCURSOR := 'mycursor';
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.tbl_groupchat(
        chatname, createdate)
VALUES ('test4', CURRENT_DATE)
RETURNING id INTO myid;
INSERT INTO public.tbl_participants (
         id_groupchat, id_profile)
         VALUES (myid, 2);         
OPEN ref_cursor for SELECT *
FROM public.tbl_participants
WHERE id_profile = 2;
END $$;


FETCH ALL  from  mycursor;
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for a DO block. This can be done in plain SQL using a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_group_chat as (
  INSERT INTO public.tbl_groupchat(
          chatname, createdate)
  VALUES ('test4', CURRENT_DATE)
  RETURNING id
)  
INSERT INTO public.tbl_participants (id_groupchat, id_profile)
select id, 2
from new_group_chat
returning *;
```

The `returning *` in the final select will return the complete row that was just inserted, making an additional `select` unnecessary.

Alternatively just use `lastval()`

```
INSERT INTO public.tbl_groupchat(
        chatname, createdate)
VALUES ('test4', CURRENT_DATE);

INSERT INTO public.tbl_participants (id_groupchat, id_profile)
values (lastval(), id);

SELECT *
FROM public.tbl_participants
WHERE id_profile = 2;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0ee6555d959759016c5d20b915e5c60a)